# Is it possible to manage the iCloud keychain?

Tags: icloud, keychain

I like to know if it is possible to manage the iCloud keychain, means, deleting elements. I tried the under the OS X keychain app in the iCloud tab but after a clean install of OS X, everything was restored. So, is it possible or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in Apples [iCloud FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US): To delete the Keychain completely, you have to deselect `Allow approving using security code` in the iCloud Account details under system preferences. After that, turn off the Keychain usage on every device that is using it. This will delete the complete keychain. Turning on the `Allow approving using security code` will result in a clean keychain.

If you want to edit items stored in the iCloud keychain you can do so via the Mac OS X keychain app or from your iDevice in the Safari preferences.

Mac OS X example: On the left, select iCloud and delete / edit items on the right.

[image: Keychain Access - editing iCloud Keychain]

Comment: As I stated, I did exactly this. But after a clean install, everything I had deleted before (which was everything), magically appeared again.

Comment: I tried it again. I had my Mac connected to the internet. Deleted the whole iCloud keychain. Restarted, checked if something is inside. Nothing. Clean installed Mavericks. Bam, everything is there! So I am very surprised it worked for you.

Comment: @DaPhil Not only does it work for me, I've used this with more than 10 other users when they wanted a clean start. You might have to get Apple support to escalate your account to engineering if it it wedged somehow. When things break, sometimes doing the intended steps to clean up doesn't work or even makes things worse. What happens if you test your two devices with another iCloud account? The log out might clear any issues with sync and you can know your software and network are functioning normally.

Comment: I found out what I have to do, still puzzles me that it seems you do not need to do it. According to [Apples support pages](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813) I needed to _deallow_ approving using a security code and turn off the keychain on all devices also.

Comment: @DaPhil interesting!  Simply signing out from keychain sync on all of your devices wasn't enough to reset things? Perhaps turning off two factor authentication sends some extra reset or makes new keys or internal ID to set a clean slate?

Comment: I guess. That's how it worked for me. Simply signing out was not enough...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the recovery steps. This will likely come up again.

Comment: Could you include it in your answer? Then it is complete.

Comment: I was going to ask if you wanted to edit it in, but if you don't I can later today.

Comment: Didn't know that I could :) I'll do it later.